Error: Attempted to navigate before mounting the Root Layout component
I'm developing an app with React Native using Expo, but I'm encountering an error with expo-router. I'm trying to navigate from the initial screen to index2 (the name is temporary until I fix the issue) when pressing the "Enter" button, but every time it takes me to that route (index2), I get the following error:

Error: Attempted to navigate before mounting the Root Layout component. Ensure the Root Layout component is rendering a Slot, or other navigator on the first render., js engine: hermes

Here's the code from _layout.tsx:
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import FontAwesome from '@expo/vector-icons/FontAwesome';
import { DarkTheme, DefaultTheme, ThemeProvider } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { useFonts } from 'expo-font';
import { Stack, Slot } from 'expo-router';
import * as SplashScreen from 'expo-splash-screen';
import { useEffect } from 'react';

// Components
import CustomHeaderNav from '@/components/customHeaderNav';
import InitialScreen from './initialScreen';

export {
  // Catch any errors thrown by the Layout component.
  ErrorBoundary,
} from 'expo-router';

export const unstable_settings = {
  // Ensure that reloading on `/modal` keeps a back button present.
  initialRouteName: 'index2',
};

// Prevent the splash screen from auto-hiding before asset loading is complete.
SplashScreen.preventAutoHideAsync();

export default function RootLayout() {
  const [loaded, error] = useFonts({
    SpaceMono: require('../assets/fonts/SpaceMono-Regular.ttf'),
    ...FontAwesome.font,
  });

  // Expo Router uses Error Boundaries to catch errors in the navigation tree.
  useEffect(() => {
    if (error) throw error;
  }, [error]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (loaded) {
      SplashScreen.hideAsync();
    }
  }, [loaded]);

  if (!loaded) {
    return null;
  }

  return <RootLayoutNav />;
}

function RootLayoutNav() {
  const [isSignedIn] = useState(true);

  return (
    isSignedIn ?
    (
      <InitialScreen />
    ) : (
      <Stack>
      <Stack.Screen name="index2" 
      options={{ 
        headerShown: true,
        header: () => <CustomHeaderNav />,
      }} />
      </Stack>
    )
  );
}


and initialScreen - where the "Entrar" button redirects:
// React
import React, {useState} from 'react';

// React-native
import { useRouter, Link } from 'expo-router';

// React-native
import { 
  View, 
  Text, 
  StyleSheet, 
  Image, 
  AppState,
  TouchableOpacity
} from 'react-native';

// Supabase
// import { supabase } from '../lib/supabase';

// Images
// const upperCircle = require('../assets/right-circle.png');
// const mountain = require('../assets/mountain.png');
// const footerIcon = require('../assets/footer-icon.png');

// Safe area insets
import { useSafeAreaInsets } from 'react-native-safe-area-context';

const InitialScreen = () => {
  const insets = useSafeAreaInsets();
  const route = useRouter();

  // AppState.addEventListener('change', (state) => {
  //   if (state === 'active') {
  //     supabase.auth.startAutoRefresh()
  //   } else {
  //     supabase.auth.stopAutoRefresh()
  //   }
  // })
  
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      {/* <Image source={upperCircle} style={styles.rightImage} /> */}
      
      <View style={[styles.middleContainer, {paddingLeft: insets.left + 10, paddingRight: insets.right + 10}]}>
        <View style={styles.imageAndTextContainer}>
          <Text style={styles.createText}>
            ¡Bienvenido/a a GREENNVI! 
          </Text>

          <Text style={styles.smallText}>
            Explora acciones, iniciativas y ayuda a la comunidad. ¡Disfruta tu viaje con nosotros!
          </Text>
        </View>
      </View>
      
      <View style={[styles.buttonContainer, {paddingBottom: insets.bottom + 20}]}>
        {/* <TouchableOpacity style={styles.loginButton} onPress={() => route.push('/home')}>
          <Text style={styles.loginText}>Entrar</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity> */}
        <Link href='/index2' style={styles.loginButton} asChild>
          <Text style={styles.loginText}>Entrar</Text>
        </Link>
        <View style={styles.registerButton}>
          <Text style={styles.registerText}>Registrarse</Text>
        </View>
      </View>
      {/* <Image source={footerIcon} style={styles.footerIcon} /> */}
    </View>
  );
}

export default InitialScreen;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'space-between',
    alignItems: 'center'
  },
  rightImage: {
    position: 'absolute',
    top: 0,
    right: 0,
    height: 300,
    width: 300
  },
  middleContainer: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  imageAndTextContainer: {
    alignItems: 'center',
    marginBottom: 40,
  },
  mountainImage: {
    height: 200,
    width: 400
  },
  createText: {
    fontWeight: '900',
    fontSize: 30,
    color: '#007472',
    textAlign: 'center',
    textTransform: 'uppercase',
  },
  smallText: {
    fontWeight: '500',
    fontSize: 17,
    color: '#007472',
    textAlign: 'center',
    width: 350,
    marginTop: 20
  },
  buttonContainer: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    marginBottom: 40,
    zIndex: 2
  },
  loginButton: {
    backgroundColor: '#007472',
    paddingTop: 10,
    paddingBottom: 10,
    paddingLeft: 20,
    paddingRight: 20,
    borderRadius: 5,
    marginRight: 20,
  },
  loginText: {
    color: '#FFF',
    fontWeight: '700'
  },
  registerButton: {
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    paddingTop: 10,
    paddingBottom: 10,
    paddingLeft: 20,
    paddingRight: 20,
    borderRadius: 5,
    borderWidth: 2,
    borderColor: '#007472',
  },
  registerText: {
    fontWeight: '700',
    color: '#007472'
  },
  footerIcon: {
    height: 300,
    width: 200,
    position: 'absolute',
    left: 0,
    bottom: 0,
    zIndex: 1
  },
});



All the screens need to be in same stack to be able to navigate. You can try router.replace() that'll replace the stack.

Try to wrap your   to  or any anlother navigation container. This error means you try to render anything without wrapping it to the navigation Slot, what happens if you have haveSignedIn = true
